# Absorption line in quasar spectrum

Tags: cosmology, spectra, quasars

I have quasar spectrum which includes emission and absorption lines. I need to find absorption lines in between 2 wavelength. How can I do it with coding?

Comment: Is the spectrum in a data file or is it just an image?

Comment: That is a data file.

Comment: In which energy range is your spectrum? Which environment / language are you using for the analysis? Do you already know the number, energies or widths of the absorption lines?

Comment: Is the x-axis energy ( wavelength, frequency) and y-axis intensity.